# USB not showing up in boot menu

Tags: boot

I'm trying to set up a dual boot for my laptop. In BIOS the USB with Ubuntu doesn't show.

Safe boot is disabled and USB legacy is enabled.

Boot menu:
[image: boot menu]

Advanced boot menu:
[image: advanced boot menu]

Comment: This ASUS doc may help. It states that the drive has to be FAT32. https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013017/#A2

Comment: The drive is FAT32.

Comment: What did you use to write the iso to the USB drive? Had a similar issue years ago, where unetbootin didn't flag the device as bootable.

Comment: Legend has it that some USB flash drives are not bootable. Do you have another? Which USB port did you use? Try others. // How did you bring up the boot menu? Transient entries could only be visible in the F11/F12 type menu (not in Setup). // You may also want to disable anything legacy again. UEFI booting is better.

Comment: @xentoo I followed a tutorial provided by The Odin Project. I created the USB with Rufus and I made that bootable with Universal USB Installer. [link](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/).

Comment: @DanielB I haven't tried using another USB. I tried all the USB ports and I brought the boot menu with F2 (the specific key for Asus TUF) and with UEFI booting from (Advance Setup > Restart now > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware settings.

Comment: Give etcher a try, rufus can be a little squirrelly. [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)

Comment: 1. Recent versions of Ubuntu should be installed with Safe Boot enabled. 2. Test the USB on another PC -- likely, as others have said, it is not bootable. Try following ItsFoss, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ , or Ubuntu, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started , directions.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestion. I used etcher and it worked perfectly.